# GPS coordinates are inaccurate on my Android Program

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get my current position of my phone via GPS in my program.

The Problem is, that either the coordinates are to inaccurate (only degrees) or no location is given. I programmed my third program now and each of them with a different tutorial, but it did not work as it should work there.

uses-permission are set, so that is not the answer ;)

So here is my code:

```
public class GpsActivity extends Activity{

private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private TextView dateField;
private TextView timeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
private LocationListener listener; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    dateField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
    timeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
    GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
    g.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
    Date d = df.getCalendar().getTime();
    dateField.setText(""+d.getDate()+"."+(d.getMonth()+1)+"."+(1980+d.getYear()));
    timeField.setText(""+g.getTime().getHours()+"h "+g.getTime().getMinutes()+"m "+g.getTime().getSeconds()+"s");


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());

        latituteField.setText(""+lat+"//"+location.getAccuracy());
        longitudeField.setText(""+lng+"//"+location.getProvider());
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
    }
    listener = new MyLocationListener(); 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps" ,10000L, 10.0f, listener); 

}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{ 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            if (location != null){ 
                    latituteField.setText(("Lat: " + location.getLatitude())); 
                    longitudeField.setText("LLong: " + location.getLongitude());
            } 
    } 
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { 

    } 
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    } 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    } 
}
}
```

Thanks for answering!

Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting just a weak signal. You may use the android location API to get an approximate location.

Make sure that you stand outside and have a free view to the sky for getting a "good" signal. Don't stand next to buildings, etc. However even if you do that you won't get an accurate signal. Phone GPSs' are optimized for energy saving and not for accuracy. They won't put a too expensive chip on your phone as well...

Comment: Further to Udo's answer, don't forget you can query the accuracy of the location fix... Discussion on accuracy here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052517/how-is-location-accuracy-measured-in-android