# Android GPS false location retirieved

Tags: android, gps, android-location

When retrieving GPS coordinates from the `LocationManager`:

1. Every retrieved `GeoPoint` is valid and accurate (+-20 meters of course)
2. There might be situations where a `GeoPoint` got retrieved, but it's not really accurate, due to poor GPS reception

Which one is the right answer?

Thanks.

Comment: 2nd and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052517/how-is-location-accuracy-measured-in-android

Comment: @Sergey - Write your comment as an answer so I will be able to mark it as the correct one please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd and here is the discussion link 
[How is location accuracy measured in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052517/how-is-location-accuracy-measured-in-android).

---

hope it helps.