# Android Geofence PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY inaccurate

Tags: android

I have created a geofence with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY and an update interval of 2mins but am having a problem when i am off wireless and on gps the accuracy of my location is very inaccurate off by like 60 meters. I see the gps icon in the notification menu but it doesn't ever settle just blinks. Is there a way to force the gps settle before a location is return or can i find out the accuracy in meters of each update?

Answer (score 0):

The GPS is per default unfortunately not very reliable, but should be accurate down to 5-10 meters in outdoor environments; it's even worse indoors as you probably imagine.

Unfortunately, the GPS accuracy furthermore depends on both the smartphone at hand and weather conditions, so there is really no specific way of determining the exact accuracy.

Apparently, the [radius of a GPS location has a 68% confidence level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13807786/2399772), indicating that there is a 68% statistically probabiliy that the location which you are given is within the radius.

You can futhermore use the [Location library in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) which holds a method called getAccuracy().

If you hereby wish, you can use this level of accuracy to determine and compare previous locations with the current one based on the accuracy (if you trust the 68% confidence level, that is).

Hope this helps

Comment: I am outdoors I changed the updated interval to 2 seconds and the geofence is still not triggering it only seems to work when i am on wifi

Comment: My answer focused solely upon retrieving the accuracy of a location-based measurement which you asked for; I am sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to stem from my device having wifi turn off . If i turn my wifi on and don't connect it i get result close to 10m accuracy but turn it off around 200m. Looks like an api bug to me