# how to determine if latitude and longitude is accurate

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, networking, maps

I am currently using the Network(wifi, data plans) to get latitude and longitude for Android (and iOS) phone. The documentation states that the coordinates may not be accurate(GPS is more accurate). Therefore, how can I determine if the Lat/Long coordinates given to me are accurate? Or, if they are not, how can I determine how much off they are?

added note: not sure if that answers my question. HOw can i use these coordinates to see if it is accurate. Im not concerned with how to program it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is location accuracy measured in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052517/how-is-location-accuracy-measured-in-android)

Comment: not sure if that answers my question. HOw can i use these coordinates to see if it is accurate. Im not concerned with how to program it.

Comment: What is your question? You get a lat/long pair and call `getAccuracy()` to find out how bad the error margin is for the values. The link I provided explains the error margin. Are you asking if values come from Wifi or GPS?

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog post [Android: Location Updates with the FusedLocationApi](http://www.adavis.info/2014/09/android-location-updates-with.html)

He uses fused location API to parse location data and keep track if coordinates are accurate. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

- You can set your request to high accuracy such as the following command:

  ```
  mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
  ```
- And you can get the accuracy value from your location object such as:

  ```
  myLocation.getAccuracy();
  ```
- The best practice for the **location** to use the **Fused Location API**,

Comment: not sure if that answers my question. HOw can i use these coordinates to see if it is accurate. Im not concerned with how to program it.

Comment: Putting this function setPriority() to HIGH_ACCURACY means the provider will returns the highest possible accuracy, and if you want to see if the returned location is more accurate or not from the previous location, you can use the Location Strategies from the following page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
But all that not preferred after appearing the Fused Location API.